# Apps Script for Google Sheets: setValues parameters

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been writing a script to copy some data from an input sheet to a database to keep track of some data. I've managed to successfully write the code for linear arrays (only one row) but when I try to copy an entire 15x15 cells range I get an error stating the parameters are not correct (suggesting the dimension of the arrays are not correct) but I can't seem to understand why.

I tried both copying directly the entire 15x15 range and creating a for loop to copy row by row 15 times but I can't mangage to make it work.

Here is the main structure:

```
  // active spreadsheet and source + target sheets
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Data Entry');
  const dstTOTSheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName('DataBaseTOT');

  var firstEmptyRowTOT = dstTOTSheet.getLastRow()+1;
```

For loop test:

```
  for (var i=0; i=14;i=i+1) {
// source cells
    var RoundInfo = srcSheet.getRange(10+i, 2, 1, 15); // 15x15 B10:P24
// target cells
    var dstTOTRoundInfo = dstTOTSheet.getRange(firstEmptyRowTOT + i, 21, 1, 15); // I am starting from column 21 because of some other data 
    // set value
    dstTOTRoundInfo.setValues(RoundInfo);
  }
```

Direct 15x15 test:

```
// source cells
var RoundInfo = srcSheet.getRange("B10:P24"); // 15x15 B10:P24
// target cells
var dstTOTRoundInfo = dstTOTSheet.getRange(firstEmptyRowTOT, 21, 15, 15);
// set value
dstTOTRoundInfo.setValues(RoundInfo);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When adding code instead of adding isolated code snippets  please add a [mcve] including the textual error message

Comment: RoundInfo is a Range, but you are passing it to setValues, which is expecting a values array, i.e. dstTOTRoundInfo.setValues(RoundInfo.getValues())

Answer (score -1):

It is actually not that difficult to understand the 2D array concept for spreadsheet, it works like this:

```js
// inner arrary is always one row of values:
// the 1st value (array index: 0)  of the inner-array is always the cell value of the 1st column of the given row.
const row_1 = ['row_value_1-1','row_value_1-2','row_value_1-3','row_value_1-4'];
const row_2 = ['row_value_2-1','row_value_2-2','row_value_2-3','row_value_2-4'];
const row_3 = ['row_value_3-1','row_value_3-2','row_value_3-3','row_value_3-4'];

// the outter-array is always the container of every rows you have in range,
// the leangth of rows (which is the leangth of each inner-array) must be the same for this structure to work in spreadsheet.
const data = [
  row_1, // the 1st value (array index: 0) of the outter-array is always the 1st row,
  row_2, // the 2nd value (array index: 1) of the outter-array is always the 2nd row, etc.
  row_3
  ];

// when you loop over such kind of 2D array, it is easier to understand with a "for... of" loop than the classic "for" loop:
for (const row of data) { // << this means "for each row of the given data"
  for (const col of row) { // << this means "for each column of the given row"
    // this structure will go through each cell of row 1, than each cell of row 2, etc., until all rows of the given data are iterated.
    console.log(col);
  }
}
/**output:
row_value_1-1
row_value_1-2
row_value_1-3
row_value_1-4
row_value_2-1
row_value_2-2
row_value_2-3
row_value_2-4
row_value_3-1
row_value_3-2
row_value_3-3
row_value_3-4
*/

// and if you need to works with the indexes of some cell, you can get the index by this:
for (const [rIndex,row] of data.entries()) {
  for (const [cIndex,col] of row.entries()) {
    console.log(rIndex,cIndex,col);
  }
}
/** output:
0 0 row_value_1-1
0 1 row_value_1-2
0 2 row_value_1-3
0 3 row_value_1-4
1 0 row_value_2-1
1 1 row_value_2-2
1 2 row_value_2-3
1 3 row_value_2-4
2 0 row_value_3-1
2 1 row_value_3-2
2 2 row_value_3-3
2 3 row_value_3-4
*/
```